# Problem with Inheritance and NullValue of a Strongly Typed DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, strongly-typed-dataset

What is the simplest/cleanest/easiest/best way to handle Null value of a Strongly Typed DataSet in the following case :

- A base class has a Nullable value that is set through it's constructor
- The derived class's constructor has Strongly Typed DataSet Row as parameter and it Throw exception when accessing a null value.

Here a simplified example to demonstrate the problem I'm facing. Any resemblance to your code is purely coincidental.

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
     Private _Number as Nullable(of integer)
     Public Sub New(Number as Nullable(of integer))
         _Number = Number 
     End Sub
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    'Throw System.Data.StrongTypingException "The value for column 'Number'
    'in table 'SomeData' is DBNull." when Number is null
    Public Sub New(DataRow as my DataDLL.SomeDataRow)
          MyBase.New(DataRow.Number) 
    End Sub

    'First statement of this 'Sub New' must be a call to 'MyBase.New' 
    'or 'MyClass.New' because base class 'BaseClass' of 'DerivedClass' 
    'does not have an accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments
    Public Sub New(DataRow as my DataDLL.SomeDataRow)
         If TermRow.IsNumberNull() Then 
              MyBase.New(Nothing)
         Else
              MyBase.New(DataRow.Number )
         End If
    End Sub  

    'Also Throw System.Data.StrongTypingException because As part of preparing 
    'the argument list for the call to IIf, the Visual Basic compiler calls 
    'every function in every expression.  
    Public Sub New(DataRow As MyData)
        MyBase.New(DirectCast(IIf(DataRow.IsNumberNull(), _
                                  Nothing, _
                                  TermRow.Number), Nullable(Of Integer)))
    End Sub

End Class
```

I put 3 `Public Sub New` only to show 3 alternatives I considered.

Comment: What is the exception thrown on your first constructor? On the second one, like it says it must be the first line, so you have to figure out how to put all your logic on one line. VB is fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes sense, you have to check for `DBNull`, which is not the same as `Integer?`

Instead of `IIF`, Try the [IF Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx), witch is new to .NET 3.5. You also have to cast `Nothing` to a `Nullable(Of Integer)` because the If function will return `0` otherwise; The return type of the return value is decided based [on the wider of the types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e%28VS.80%29.aspx) of the true-part and the false-part.

```
Public Sub New(DataRow As MyData)
    MyBase.New(If(DataRow.IsNumberNull(), _
                  DirectCast(Nothing, Nullable(Of Integer)), _
                  DataRow.Number))
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.0? If so you can use the `If(...)` statement.

Comment: It look like the `if(...)` statement was introduced with .NET 3.5! So I was able to use it. Meanwhile, the if was returning `0` instead of `Nothing` when `IsNumberNull` was `true`. The solution is to Cast `Nothing` to a `Nullable(Of Integer)` instead of casting the whole if statement. Anyway, I edited you answer (again), please accept my edit so I will accept you answer and award you the bounty that I prematurely placed last night.

Comment: @David I'm curious to see how `OrElse` could be use in this particular case.